# Suggest term search result not proper in elasticsearch

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am using elasticsearch 6.1 version and I want to use "Suggester" of its feature. I have dumped data in the format its required for suggester.

I have used these queries.

```
PUT /hotels
{
 "mappings": {
"hotel" : {
  "properties" : {
   "name" : { "type" : "keyword" },
   "city" : { "type" : "keyword" },
   "name_suggest" : {
     "type" :     "completion"
   }
 }
 }
 }
 }

put hotels/hotel/1
{
"name" :         "Mercure Hotel Munich",
"city" :         "Munich",
"name_suggest" : "Mercure Hotel Munich"
  }

put /hotels/hotel/2
 {
  "name" :         "Hotel Monaco",
  "city" :         "Munich",
"name_suggest" : "Hotel Monaco"
 }

put /hotels/hotel/3
 {
  "name" :         "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City",
 "city" :         "Munich",
 "name_suggest" : "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City"
  }
```

Then I fire my search query that is

```
Post  http://localhost:9200/hotels/_search 
      {
        "suggest": {
        "name_suggest": {
             "text": "h",
           "completion": {
              "field": "name_suggest"
           }
      }
    }
 }
```

I get the output result. It only return me the 2 data that is "Hotel Monaco" but it doesn't suggest me  "Mercure Hotel Munich" it has hotel.

I want both in my suggest result set 
I have tried with "prefix" as well.

Has anyone tried it. Please suggest me any solution to it.